# Fabric Docker image version of 1.1.0-alpha does not match this newer version of BYFN and is unsupport

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-16.04

Fabric Docker image version of 1.1.0-alpha does not match this newer version of BYFN and is unsupport. Either move to a later version of Fabric or checkout an earlier version of fabric-samples.

Local fabric binaries and docker images are
  out of  sync. This may cause problems.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPvhI.png)

is their any terminal commands in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your local environment by running

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the fabric-samples folder, check the git branch by:

```
git branch
```

Just try to change to another branch and try, for example, using Fabric 1.0 :
[image]